# Display image from Mongodb with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection "**image**" and "**image_ids** "in my mongoDB:

**image:**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac"),
        "reference" : "5424991"
}
```

**images_ids:**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e652995ac12ed3fecb85f"),
        "image" : "D0000001.PNG",
        "fid" : ObjectId("542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac"),
        "reference" : "5424991"
}
```

How I can be able to display D0000001.PNG with NodeJS? I mean, to do the link with and API.

[EDIT] we have also

```
fs.chunks:

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e684a8a1cec178a172673"),
        "n" : 1,
        "data" : BinData(0,"2N6DSSfbCN/LLacNDYrJUQDEZgimMUwFpQGoJP0RU19Bi4PM82DjrUnKhE/P9v7P8ZveD1oDpFBM0iml9NE3WQmAvYFoG+nhD73Jm4N9b4LpylaAN5Ef+gVdgGSTAfSUwOikXoVick5pSQCkRmTCU5NT9VVfjHdAx74/ZhFRj+TIRjzlAhzkACBElzgMwGCo7tX+FYrpQLJ5KRmXiwFFwsNtHHzXiK1eu+CG1FumhGpA/qdG8CdDgD1xUHEcerMGO/eLGR9ML7ni/VjXxWzqp2j5DG2/WuKNv7xd3Kz/vr0MctJhuaBIl35YrKhdLnzqDa0uDa6bm4jz+eNyAI2hQbayGo4kVPFe8W7wFpY7qfBvnB9kbocxfZSdADDUNwYaydpT8lIcKEN9XfQJOYZvHp0El"),
        "files_id" : ObjectId("542e684a8a1cec178a172671")
}

fs.files:

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e65378axdeckhb0"),
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2012-11-01"),
        "length" : 15673,
        "chunkSize" : 33222,
        "md5" : "f66e6654854a28e3672cfhds334d223b55a1"
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are storing the images in mongodb? Where the image content is? We would normally use the GridFS API for this. But based on your snippet, it looks like all you are looking for is: <image_ids model>.populate({path: "fid"}).

Comment: we have other things. Just edited the post. Thanks!